# Slow while loop in tkinter after reboot

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, loops, tkinter, vb6

i'm trying to add some windows on the top of an existing vb6 app.

`

```
from threading import Thread
from tkinter import *
import pyautogui
import win32gui
import time


#coordinates of the target image that i use to decide if i have to show the tk windows
target=(83,396)
target2=(612,73)
targetp=(153,204,0)
target2p=(247,87,70)

#windows geometry
wg1=(221,229,795,160)
wg2=(154,162,11,482)

f = True

#names of the vb program's windows that have to cover the left window
ws = ["Parametri di lavorazione", "Opzioni", "Configurazione tabelle DXF"]


#windows thread
def wins():
    global win10
    global win20
    win10 = Tk()
    win10.overrideredirect(True)
    win10.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % wg1)
    img1 = PhotoImage(file = "c:\\users\\utente\\desktop\\img1.png")
    l1= Label(win10, i=img1)
    l1.pack()
    win20 = Toplevel(win10)
    img2 = PhotoImage(file = "c:\\users\\utente\\desktop\\img2.png")
    l2 = Label(win20, i=img2)
    l2.pack()
    win20.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % wg2)
    win20.overrideredirect(True)
    win10.mainloop()

#thread to check if the windows have to be showed based on the first target
def cl():
    global win10
    global win20
    s = True
    while True:
        if s:
            if pyautogui.pixel(target[0],target[1]) != targetp:
                win10.withdraw()
                win20.withdraw()
                s = False
        else:
            if pyautogui.pixel(target[0],target[1]) == targetp:
                win10.deiconify()
                win20.deiconify()
                s = True


#thread to handle other windows on the original app 
def rd():
    ws2 = []
    while True:
        for i in ws:
            ws2.append(win32gui.FindWindow(0,i))
        for i in ws2:
            if i:
                a,b,c,d= win32gui.GetWindowRect(i)
                win32gui.MoveWindow(i,1024-(c-a-8),-8,c-a,d-b,True)
                while True:
                    if pyautogui.pixel(target2[0],target2[1]) != target2p:
                        win10.withdraw()
                        break
                while True:
                    if pyautogui.pixel(target2[0],target2[1]) == target2p:
                        win10.deiconify()
                        break
        ws2=[]



t1 = Thread(target=wins)
t2 = Thread(target=cl)
t3 = Thread(target=rd)
t1.start()
time.sleep(1)
t2.start()
t3.start()
    
#while loop to make my windows always on top
while True:
    win10.attributes("-topmost",True)
    win20.attributes("-topmost",True)
```

`

The old app is set to be always on top, so i had to add a while loop at the end of the code that sets the two new windows topmost.
If i don't do this, my windows disappear as soon as i click on the old program's main window.
The code runs fine on my windows 10 machine until i reboot the operating system.
After the reboot, the last while loop become very slow, so that even the operation of minimizing the main window takes about 5 seconds.
Do you have any idea on how to fix this?

I also tried to insert the while loop in a thread letting the windows mainloop outside any method, but same result.
Until the reboot it all goes fine, after i power on the machine again in becomes very slow.